# magento product qty as radio buttons

Tags: php, magento-1.7, product

I am building a magento store that has a virtual product.

I would like to add radio buttons for some set product quantities. For example have 4 options on the page for 5 Qty, 10 Qty, 15 Qty and 20 Qty.

Then under this have an option to manually enter the qty.

Comment: Currently on magento customers choose the qty they want to order by entering a number into a text field and pressing add to cart.

I want to amend this so that customers have the option to choose a set qty by a radio button but still keep the standard option. 

I have looked in detail of how to do this but cannot seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: i added an answer, but deleted - did not read the question carefully, sorry. Accidentally ignored that you want to keep the textfield.

Comment: I might actually do this without the text field, could you add your answer back on for me please.